# Symfony infinite loop leading to ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error

Tags: php, symfony, http-redirect

I would like to implement a [*Remember me*](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/security/remember_me.html) feature. Since I didn't get any custom authenticator, I added one.
After adding it, I faced some issues about redirections. On the navigator, the page is looping between "login" page and my destination page.

This loop ends in a

> *ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS* error.

This error only occurs on page that requires user being logged.

Symfony version: 5.4.

---

**security.yaml**

```
security:
    password_hashers:
        App\Entity\User: 'auto'

       Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
            algorithm: 'auto'
            cost:      15

    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email

    enable_authenticator_manager: true

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            provider: app_user_provider
            custom_authenticators:
                - App\Security\CustomAuthenticator
            form_login:
                login_path: app_login
                check_path: app_login
                use_referer: true
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                target: index
            user_checker: App\Security\UserChecker

            remember_me:
                secret: '%kernel.secret%' # required
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                signature_properties: ['password']
                
        secured_area:
            form_login:
                enable_csrf: true

    access_control:
        - { path: '^/admin',           roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
        - { path: '^/tableau-de-bord', roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
        - { path: '^/profil',          roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
        - { path: '^/dashboard',       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
        - { path: '^/profile',         roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `access_control` section, try replacing `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` by `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED`:

**security.yaml**

```
security:
    ...
    access_control:
        - { path: '^/admin',           roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }
        - { path: '^/tableau-de-bord', roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }
        - { path: '^/profil',          roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }
        - { path: '^/dashboard',       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }
        - { path: '^/profile',         roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }
```

From the [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/5.0/security.html#checking-to-see-if-a-user-is-logged-in-is-authenticated-fully):

> ***IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY***: This is similar to *IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED*, but stronger. Users who are logged in only because of a "remember me cookie" will have *IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED* but will **not have** *IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY*.